# Displaying a preview of a webpage inside imageview

Tags: android

I want to get a preview of a webpage for a given url, how can I achieve that?

I have a simple `Activity` with a `layout` only with an `ImageView`, and I want to display a preview of the web page inside the `ImageView`.

The only solution will probably be to have a small disabled webview and load the url from the webview.